# Trying to implement infinite scrolling with VueJS and Axios

Tags: javascript, vue.js, scroll, axios

As stated in the title, I am trying to implement infinite scrolling in a Vue project as a university project.

I have imported the requested API through axios and would like my app to check the page the API gets and add "1" whenever I scroll to the bottom of the page.

I'm trying to use Observer to do that, but I think I'm lacking the basics, as I'm not able to make it work properly.

I've also tried vue-infinite-scroll but.. well, I'm clueless as to why it does not work and I ended up deleting the code lines where I tried to use it out of exasperation.

If you take a look at my CodeSandbox link (https://codesandbox.io/s/20082020-ldomq?file=/src/components/GamesList.vue) you can see I'm trying to implement the scrolling feature in GamesList.vue (which is where I request the API). Here's the code snippet:

```
export default {
  name: "GameList",
  data() {
    return {
      list: undefined
    };
  },
  components: {
    Observer
  },
  mounted() {
    Vue.axios.get("https://api.rawg.io/api/games?page=1").then(resp => {
      this.list = resp.data.results;
    });
  },
  methods: {
    async intersected() {
      this.page++;
    }
  }
};
```

I wish I could give you more information and I will certainly try if requested, but my knowledge in programming is very limited and I'm not sure how much I would be able to help you. I'm sorry about that.

Thank you in advance, I wish you a wonderful day.

Comment: Aside of you r question. There is a package that you are trying to make https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-infinite-loading

Comment: You didn't write what is going wrong. Do you get an error or the requests aren't send or the same requests are send?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I checked your code. You are probably trying to do the same as in this tutorial: https://vueschool.io/articles/vuejs-tutorials/build-an-infinite-scroll-component-using-intersection-observer-api/
And It's works in that tutorial. Observer works as expected in your code, but you don't make any request on intersected event.
I changed you component and now it works:

```
export default {
  name: "GameList",
  data() {
    return {
      list: [],
      page: 1
    };
  },
  components: {
    Observer
  },
  methods: {
    async intersected() {
      const res = await fetch(
        `https://api.rawg.io/api/games?page=${this.page}&_limit=50`
      );

      this.page++;
      const items = await res.json();
      this.list = [...this.list, ...items.results];
    }
  }
};
```

Comment: Dear Konowy, thank you very much for your answer. Yes, I was trying to follow this tutorial!

Programming is hard but I'm glad helpful people like you exist. I wish you the best!